# Polymer - items in paper-listbox

Tags: polymer, polymer-2.x

If I want to create a paper selector from an array with polymer it looks quite cumbersome:

```
...
        <paper-listbox
                slot="dropdown-content">
            <template is="dom-repeat" items="[[myItemList]]">
                <paper-item>
                    [[item]]
                </paper-item>
            </template>
        </paper-listbox>
...
```

Especially it looks like the `dom-repeat` template is always required. Is there any shortcut like

```
    <paper-listbox item-list=[[myItemList]]
            slot="dropdown-content">
            <paper-item>
                [[item]]
            </paper-item>
    </paper-listbox>
```

or does everyone implement an own web component for this pattern that does that?

Answer (score -1):

Already built in.

```
<paper-listbox items="[[myItemList]]" as="item">
    <paper-item>[[item]]</paper-item>   
</paper-listbox>
```

Comment: That shouldn't matter.  The `[[]]` are one-way model-binding, so it should work with readOnly properties.

Comment: Well, it does not :) . It's described in the documentation:
https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/devguide/properties#read-only

"When a property only "produces" data and never consumes data, this can be made explicit to avoid accidental changes from the host by setting the readOnly flag"

Comment: And here is the accompanying part of the documentation that shows where read-only data is bound using double-brackets: https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/devguide/data-system#data-flow-control

Comment: Yes, and according to this one `readOnly` makes dataflow oneway upward (from child -> host) and not the other way round ;)

Comment: I don't think this is correct. `as` is not listed as a attribute and `paper-listbox` is not a repeater. Also, double brackets doesn't force a attribute(not the same as host prop) out of being read only

Comment: @dman `paper-listbox` inherits from `Polymer.IronSelectableBehavior`, which is where the `items`/`as` attributes come from. You can see that in the [documentation](https://www.webcomponents.org/element/PolymerElements/paper-listbox/elements/paper-listbox). I don't understand why everyone is focused on `readOnly`; yes, it's readonly by design. The array itself does not change--just the selected elements.